# "Order by" when querying relation

Tags: laravel

I have a Project table and a pivot table "like_project" which has 2 columns : user_id and project_id, so users can like Projects

I'm trying to list all the Projects and order them by number of likes, by using the "has" method, like this :

```
$projects = Project::has('likes')->paginate(10);
```

the issue is that I don't know how to order by number of likes, I have a function on my Project model to count the number of likes for a project :

```
public function getTotalLikes(){
    return sizeof($this->likes()->getRelatedIds()); //I could use $this->likes()->count()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to write out a long SQL query to run an GROUP/ORDER BY command I'd just run the eloquent collection's sort method once you get the projects back.

`$projects->sort(function($project) {
    return $project->likes->count();
});`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your likes are stored exactly, but most straightforward way is simple join (suppose MySQL):

```
$projects = Project::join('like_project as lp', 'lp.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
              ->groupBy('projects.id')
              ->orderByRaw('count(lp.project_id) desc')
              ->select('projects.*') // and if needed: DB::raw('count(lp.project_id) as likesCount')
              ->paginate(10);
```